# adaptive bitrate in android

Tags: android

In my android application, I would like to shift from 2G or 3G depending on the bitrate available.
Is there any method that I can get the bitrate in Android?

Comment: What kind of 'adaptive bitrate' are you talking about? Do you mean Adaptive Bitrate Streaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android (or any other device) can not give you available bitrate of your network, as this depends on the type of network, its configuration, saturation and other environmental conditions.

However you can get a type of network and devise typical speeds from this. Use [`ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#getType%28%29) and `getSybType()`.

`getType()` gives you [`ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#TYPE_MOBILE), etc..

`getSybType()` gives you [`TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html), etc

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.Then is it not possible to switch as per the network bandwidth in android?If possible could you please let me know if i can get 2G and 3 G details anyhow

Comment: I believe I did explain that in my answer. You need to check if you network is `ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE` and then further if it a 3G network like `TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS` or `TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA`, etc..

Comment: Thanks Peter for quick response